# Qml FontLoader not loading the custom font

Tags: qt, fonts, qml, qt5, qtquick2

I am trying to use the Google font `Inter Regular TTF` (I tested with some other font files as well) but FontLoader is not loading the font, below is my code.

I have copied the font file `.ttf` in the `.qrc` resource "fonts" folder.
I have defined a common style file and loading the Fonts that are used across the application.

```
// ------- Style.qml --------
pragma Singleton
import QtQuick 2.12

QtObject {

    property var myFontInterRegular: FontLoader {
        source: "qrc:/fonts/Inter-Regular.ttf"
        onStatusChanged: {
            console.log("onStatusChanged status:"+status); // Not getting called
        }
    }
}
```

The signal `onStatusChanged` is not getting called so I think my Font is not loading.
I am using the font as below:

```
// ------- TestPage.qml --------
import QtQuick 2.12
import "."

Rectangle {
    id: parentRect
    width: parent.width
    height: parent.height

    Text {
        id: myTxt
        text: "Hello In Inter-Regular"
        font.family: Style.myFontInterRegular.name // Getting error "name" not defined
    }
}
```

When I run the code I get an error:
`TypeError: Cannot read property 'name' of undefined` for the line `Style.myFontInterRegular.name`

Comment: It works when I try it. As a sanity check, try doing a clean and then rebuilding. I had to do that for some reason when I first added my font to my resource file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What I have used and works:

```
// ------assets/Style.qml---------
pragma Singleton

Item {
    property alias fontAwesome: fontAwesomeLoader.name
    FontLoader {
        id: fontAwesomeLoader
        source: "qrc:/fonts/fontawesome.ttf"
    }
}
```

```
// ------- TestPage.qml --------
import QtQuick 2.12
import assets 1.0 // This works using qmldir and assets.qrc

Rectangle {
    id: parentRect
    width: parent.width
    height: parent.height

    Text {
        id: myTxt
        text: "Hello In Inter-Regular"
        font.family: Style.fontAwesome
    }
}
```

```
// ---assets.qrc----
<RCC>
    <qresource prefix="/assets">
         <file alias="qmldir">assets/qmldir</file>
         <file alias="Style.qml">assets/Style.qml</file>
    </qresource>
</RCC>
```

```
// ---assets/qmldir----
module assets
singleton Style 1.0 Style.qml
```

Comment: Thanks, I was missing the `qmldir` file. As per the documentation we need to have this file added in the root of the project.